# Fetching bit field with mysql_query()

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my code:

```
$query = "SELECT Username, EmailVerified, Blocked FROM user";
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
print_r($row);
```

Field `Username` is **string** and `EmailVerified` and `Blocked` are of type **bit**. The line `print_r($row)` displays the value of `Username` field but not the other two. I tried mysql_fetch_object(), mysql_fetch_row(), mysql_fetch_array() also, but same result.

Can't we fetch bit fields with mysql_query()?

Comment: What does it display for those two? They should be 0 or 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to cast the BIT field to an integer ->

```
SELECT Username, CAST(EmailVerified AS unsigned integer) AS EmailV, CAST(Blocked AS unsigned integer) AS Block FROM User
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can but they are retrieved as strings, and most likely end up being unprintable characters. You can get the values as numbers like so:

```
$query = "SELECT Username, EmailVerified, Blocked FROM user";
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$row['EmailVerified'] = ord( $row['EmailVerified'] );
$row['Blocked'] = ord( $row['Blocked'] );
print_r($row);
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Yet, I would prefer **nicky77**'s approach.

Comment: @kush.impetus cool, they are still strings though so you need to convert to number anyway in PHP after that query if you were to use them :P

Comment: @Esalija: You are right. But you know, they will costly operations in terms of CPU time, in case it counts.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using [BIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/bit-type.html) and converting it each time you need to use, you can use [BOOL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html) (which is already a [TINYINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html)) and store TRUE (1) or FALSE (0) values.

Comment: I am sorry but, I am using Navicat for MySQL version 8.0.26 for managing my MySQL databases. I don't see any datatype named **BOOL** there. That might be because my version of Navicat is older. I will see to it. Thank anyways.

Comment: @kush the `BOOL` type is just an alias to `TINYINT(1)`, so you can use this type in your field.